# Payara Server Startup Exception

Tags: java, glassfish, java-ee-7, payara, glassfish-5

I am getting this error in Payara 5.194 during startup in centos.I try changing setting to default setting and change port but i am still getting this error

```
[2020-04-03T10:36:10.144+0545] [Payara 5.194] [WARNING] [] [fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigProviderResolverImpl] [tid: _ThreadID=21 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1585889460207] [timeMillis: 1585889470144] [levelValue: 900] [[
      Timeout out waiting for Microprofile Config startup
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Payara Microprofile Config needs running server environment to work. Either it's not running, or you're experiencing a race condition
        at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigProviderResolverSync.await(ConfigProviderResolverSync.java:55)
        at fish.payara.nucleus.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigProviderResolverSync.getConfig(ConfigProviderResolverSync.java:77)
        at org.eclipse.microprofile.config.ConfigProvider.getConfig(ConfigProvider.java:93)
        at fish.payara.microprofile.healthcheck.HealthCheckService.postConstruct(HealthCheckService.java:119)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1268)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:309)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    ]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this issue is fixed in Payara 5.201. I did not get this error in 5.201 but my startup is slow.

Also Check this https://github.com/payara/Payara/pull/4486

Answer (score 1):

It look like this error is due to slow startup time of server. Payara server was slow due to memory setting issue of Payara server and now I am not getting this error after I fix startup issue.

Edited: I also found this https://github.com/payara/Payara/pull/4480 and it looks like startup error due to slow startup has been fix in new version of Payara server.